# iOS sandbox IAP fails in 10.3

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have some IAP code running since iOS 9.0 w/o problems. Today I updated to 10.3 and I am not anymore able to test IAPs in the sandbox environment. I now use Xcode 8.3. Specifically what happens is this:

- the list of products gets loaded (so connectivity is OK)
- the product gets added to the payment queue
- GUI asks for appleID password
- when entered I get .failed in the from the paymentQueue
- then the GUI pops up the "Accept IAP purchase" (env. sandbox)
- if I say OK I get "no connection to iTunes Store"

Does anybody have similar problems with 10.3 ?

Please note that my same code is running without problems since several months now with earlier iOS versions and that I definitely HAVE internet connection on the test device.

Thanks

Comment: When I read that other do also have that problem, I have filed a bug report to apple. Let's see...

Comment: I'm having issues with sandbox IAP failing on 10.3 as well.